# SQL query performance and Join tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling to get the best query for my Q&A website. As a simplified example, I have 3 tables (questions, answers and users):

**table_users**

```
UserID  FirstName
1       John
2       Jack
3       Ana
4       Mary
```

**table_questions**

```
QuestionID  fkUserID Title
1           4        What is...?
2           2        Where is...?
3           1        How to...?
4           3        How much...?
```

**table_answers**

```
AnswerID    fkQuestionID    fkUserID  Answer
1           1               3         It is...
2           2               1         It is located in ZZ...
3           2               4         It is located in YY...
4           3               2         You have to...
```

I am creating a newsfeed to:

1. Show the last answers ordered by the added date
2. If the there are 2
   answers for the same question, the newsfeed will only show the last
   answer (avoid duplication). In the example the newsfeed would only show the AnswerID 3 (It is located in YY...) and would skip the AnswerID 2.
3. The newsfeed will show the first name of the person that
   created the question as well the person that answered it, both are located in the same table of users

So far, I created this query below, however:

I am having some performance/speed issues and I am not being able to only show the last answer of a question (issue 2), the DISTINCT select doesn't work as expected in this case.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT (A.fkQuestionID) as QuestionID,
Q.Title,
A.AnswerID as AnswerID,
A.Answer,
U1.FirstName as AnswerFirstName,
Q.pkQuestionID,
U2.FirstName as QuestionFirstName

FROM table_answers as A
INNER JOIN table_questions as Q ON Q.QuestionID=A.fkQuestionID
INNER JOIN table_users as U1 ON U1.UserID=A.fkUserID
INNER JOIN table_users as U2 ON U2.UserID=Q.fkUserID
ORDER BY A.AnswerID DESC
```

I'd like to return the expected result as:

```
QuestionID  AnswerID  AnswerFirstName   QuestionFirstName
3           4         Jack              John
2           3         Mary              Jack
1           1         Ana               Mary
```

Any help would be very welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @FelixPamittan it is MySQL

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MAX` inside a subquery and do `JOIN`s to get the needed columns:

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/448746)</kbd>

```
SELECT
    q.QuestionID,
    q.title,
    u1.FirstName AS Asker,
    a.AnswerID,
    a.answer,
    u2.FirstName AS Answerer
FROM table_questions q
INNER JOIN table_users u1
    ON u1.UserID = q.fkUserID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        fkQuestionID, MAX(AnswerID) AS AnswerID
    FROM table_answers
    GROUP BY fkQuestionID
) t
    ON t.fkQuestionID = q.QuestionID
INNER JOIN table_answers a
    ON a.AnswerID = t.AnswerID
    AND a.fkQuestionID = t.fkQuestionID
INNER JOIN table_users u2
    ON u2.UserID = a.fkUserID
```

*Replace the `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` if you wish to include questions without answers.*

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `fkQuestionID` to get the `max(AnswerID)` and then use it in further `join` like this.

```
SELECT 
q.QuestionID,
q.Title,
a1.AnswerID as AnswerID,
a1.Answer,
U1.FirstName as AnswerFirstName,
q.pkQuestionID,
U2.FirstName as QuestionFirstName
FROM
(SELECT MAX(AnswerID) as AnswerID,fkQuestionID FROM table_answers GROUP BY fkQuestionID ) as a2
INNER JOIN table_answers a1  ON a1.fkQuestionID = a2.fkQuestionID AND a1.AnswerID = a2.AnswerID
INNER JOIN table_questions q ON q.QuestionID = a2.fkQuestionID 
INNER JOIN table_users as U1 ON U1.UserID=a1.fkUserID
INNER JOIN table_users as U2 ON U2.UserID=q.fkUserID
ORDER BY a2.AnswerID DESC
```

Comment: tks a lot! is it possible, to create a query in order to include also questions without answers, and order everything by all recent activities?

Comment: `group by` query would be `left outer join`, along with `table_answers`. since there is no common time, i am not sure how we can define if a question if recent or an answer to a different question is more recent as the ids are different in different tables and there is no date in any of them

Comment: got it! what if both tables (table_questions and table_answers) have a timestamp column?

Comment: you can use a `GREATEST(q.timestamp,a.timestamp) DESC`  in order by

Answer (score 0):

Plz try like this

```
SELECT  QuestionID ,fkUserID,title,ANS.Answer
FROM    table_questions QST
INNER JOIN (SELECT fkQuestionID,MAX(AnswerID) AnswerID
            FROM    table_answers
            GROUP BY fkQuestionID) ANS ON ANS.fkQuestionID = QST.QuestionID
INNER JOIN table_answers LANS ON LANS.AnswerID = ANS.AnswerID
```